gRPC memory usage during stream
According to this answer: stream reduces the maximum amount of memory required to process each message
I wonder when sending a large file by separating it into chunks then sent through a gRPC stream, do all the chunks needs to be hold in memory until the whole process is done?
If a file with size X MB needs to to be passed though multiple services(means sending and receiving in between multiple times), does that mean theoretically each service will need to have 2X MB memory available?


do all the chunks needs to be hold in memory until the whole process is done?

No; the stream can even be theoretically infinite - all that is rooted by gRPC is the current message; that's basically the point of streaming. Of course, if your code roots them (for example, adding everything to a list/array), then... bad things.

Thanks @Mark. I would like to learn how memory is managed while streaming. Should I look for that in gRPC documentation or maybe Kotlin Flow documenation?

@user3145047 the specifics will almost certainly be platform/framework/language specific; gRPC is multi-platform
